# How to predict temperature for the 4th day, given temperatures for previous days, using a linear perceptron?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, prediction, training-data, perceptron

I have four sets of data (3 for training, 1 for testing) that include the hour of the day and temperatures in this format:
**Time** | **Temperature**
5, 60
6, 63
7,70
8,73
9,78
10,81.5
11,85.1
12,87
13,90
I need to train and test a perceptron and then predict what the temperatures will be on the next day at the same hours.
I am trying to use Matlab to do this and I know I am supposed to normalize the data and use time-series prediction. However I can't figure out how to start.
I don't understand what the inputs and outputs are, and what activations function to use to make the output linearly from -infinity to +infinity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you won't have to use a perceptron for this task as you want to perform regression and not classification. (Perceptron is a binary classifier see [Matlab documentation.](https://de.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/perceptron.html))

To start with normalization: You need to adjust your data such that the mean is zero and the standard deviation equals 1. For example:

```
data = rand(1,100);
data = (data - mean(data))/sqrt(var(data));
```

You can interpret your input and output as follows:
You have an underlying function which maps your time-values to the temperature values (*f:time->temperature*). Time is the independent variable and temperature the dependent variable (see for example [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis)). And you want to find an approximation for f based on your input data.

For time series regression you will find a detailed example [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/econ/examples/time-series-regression-i-linear-models.html). If you
are required to use a feedforward network you can also take a look at [this](https://de.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/patternnet.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do I normalize both columns or just the temperature calumn? And also what activation function do I use?

Comment: You only normalize the dependent variable (temperature).

Comment: For the Matlab functions above you don't have to specify an activation function. However common activation functions are sigmoid, tangens and ReLU  functions.

Comment: Sorry to keep asking questions. So I just train three times and test once and then predict? How do I see the training or testing error? Thanks again :)

Comment: The Matlab functions let you input your training data as one matrix so you will train only one time.

Comment: @Regza123 Then you predict for your testing data to gauge the results of your training. And then you predict for the other days.

Comment: I just need to make one prediction for the next day. And I have three separate training files for three days for the same hours, how do I train once? Should I combine the files? Thanks!

Comment: Depends which function you are using. In most cases of Matlab functions I am aware of you combine your training data as two vectors `ti` and `te`  with `ti` being the vector of time points and `te` being the measured temperature.

Comment: So in your case: `ti=[5 6 7...]`, `te=[60 63 70...]` then you initialize with `net = patternnet(...)` (for example) and execute 'net = train(net,ti,te)`.